# What is the effect of using Electrical Boxes / Fuseboxes in Cyberpunk 2077?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

In Cyberpunk 2077, in enemy territories there are fuseboxes or electrical boxes at walls. I check the criteria to use them but once I do, I don't understand their effect.

What effect has using the Fusebox?
[image: Fusebox]

Comment: I assume you mean access points, like this? https://assets.rpgsite.net/images/images/000/094/043/article/cyberpunk_2077_make_money_access_point.webp - these allow you to hack resources/get xp

Comment: @kalina No, I don't mean access points. I literally mean fuseboxes. I assume they disable certain devices or disable electrical locks, but I'm totally unsure as I see no effect after using them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All fuse boxes can be quick hacked to cause a localised distraction (which will attract the attention of nearby enemies) or initiate an overload (which will cause a small localised explosion damaging nearby enemies).

Using your technical ability on a fuse box (when available) will temporarily disable all cameras on the local network. Both quick hacking and using your technical ability on a fuse box will give you experience.

In addition to this, a small number of fuse boxes can be interacted with as part of missions (such as the fuse box to enable power during the Ghost Town mission) and several others (for example at the back of Clouds) can be interacted with using the technical ability.

Comment: Is this right, as I can manually open them and re-wire them without any need to hack at all. Scanning them shows they're linked to a variety of electrical systems, such as cameras and lights.

Comment: @DavidYell can you give an example of a location where hacking a fuse box had a specific effect beyond distracting enemies?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I upvoted the question as I didn't notice it had any effect at all.

Comment: There is a fuse box you can interact with in the back of Clouds that requires technical ability, but this doesn't appear to actually do anything as far as I can tell (I've done the mission several times now with and without interacting with the fuse box)

Comment: There are more Fuse Boxes like the one in Clouds around the world; they're interacted with via "Technical Ability" checks completely independent of any hacking interactions, and that's clearly what this question is about.

Answer (score 3):

There’s one in a hostile area in the badlands that turns off all cameras in the area, the rest probably have similar effects

Answer (score 0):

you can use your "PING" ability to find where these "fuse boxes" are, and use them as just a simple way to gain some easy EXP if youre a playing "tech" build as far as your character skills goes... Example: Using "PING"in the "DISASTERPIECE" mission whhen you sneak into the warehouse from the second floor, (in a wide open area such as the "Warehouse" this is more easily noticed.) but in that mission, its inhabited by the "scavs" and using "PING" will show lines coming off the item you are pinging initially, and then they will sometimes show orangish lines leading back to the electrical systems/networks they are tied to, then if you keep watching they will change into "blueish-green" colored lines, it's my belief that these secondary lines are showing the items in the network that have a direct effector are directly affected BY on the item you are pinging. Thus letting you know where to score some easy tech points by interacting with the circuit-box OR, to gain some quickhack parts and money via tracing back to network "Hubs" that you can "Jack in" to.